# VueJS HTTP Tests - Mock not reflected in component render

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, axios, jestjs, axios-mock-adapter

I'm trying to complete some lightweight tests based on render output focussing on initial load and user interaction.

I am working on a HTTP test for a login component. As you would expect, it's a basic component containing an email field, a password and a button. When the user clicks the button, it calls a method which makes an axios call to an endpoint. The specific test case that I am working on is the "invalid submission" test where I simulate a user simply hitting the submit button without entering any information, expecting the application to output errors.

I first tried going down the [vue-test-utils](https://test-utils.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/http-requests.html) route and triggering a button click and using Jest's `spyOn` function to watch for `axios.post` requests. Despite various attempts to delay using `await` and various other suggested `Promise` approaches, nothing was being rendered and `spyOn` was not reporting any form of `axios` calls, so the test failed despite following the documentation.

My research into Vue HTTP testing patterns led me to Mock tests. I had some success with Mock tests using [axios-mock-adapter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-mock-adapter) with the `expect()` cases checking the `axios` calls, however any sort of check on the render itself would fail. The mock tests had no affect on the vdom, despite having the `mount` configured to `attachTo: document.body` and various attempts to delay the checks with promises.

```
describe("when API call is unsuccessful", () => {
    it('displays error messages', async () => {  
        let spy = jest.spyOn(axios, "post");
        let result = null;
        mock.onPost(url).reply(422, mockResult);

        await axios.post(url).then(function (response) {
            result = response
        }).catch((error) => {
            result = error.response.data
        });

        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1) <-- Passes
        expect(result).toEqual(mockResult) <-- Passes
        expect(wrapper.get('.error--text')) <-- Fails
    })
})
```

For the sake of trial & error, I even added a line into the catch function that set the `wrapper.vm.errors` data property to the `result` variable (which is what the component does following a failed request) and then the dom checks passed.

Am I missing something? Is there a clear, simple way of mocking an HTTP request and updating a component accordingly that I am just missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a small breakthrough with this. I switched over to [Moxios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moxios) and had success with mocking HTTP requests that impact the component and its render.

login.spec.js:

```
import { mount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils';
import VueCompositionApi from '@vue/composition-api'
import axios from 'axios';
import Vuetify from "vuetify";
import moxios from 'moxios';
import expect from 'expect';


beforeEach(() => {
    moxios.install()
    const localVue = createLocalVue();
    localVue.use(VueCompositionApi);
    vuetify = new Vuetify();

    jest.spyOn(axios, 'post').mockResolvedValue(mockResult)

    wrapper = mount(localVue.component('login', require('../../resources/js/components/Login.vue').default), {
        vuetify,
        attachTo: document.body
    });
})

afterEach(function () {
    moxios.uninstall()
})

afterAll(() => {
    wrapper.destroy()
})

describe("when API call is unsuccessful", () => {
    it('displays error messages', (done) => {  
        wrapper.find('button').trigger('click')

        moxios.wait(function () {
            let request = moxios.requests.mostRecent()
            request.respondWith({
              status: 422,
              response: mockResult
            }).then(function(response){
                done()
                expect(response).rejects
                expect(wrapper.get('.error--text'))
            })
        })
    })
})
```